# Mongodb - get distinct values by date/time within the hour

Tags: mongodb, distinct-values

If I wish to ask for a unique values I can do:

```
db.getCollection('cars').distinct('deparutre_date')
```

results:

```
2021-05-03 15:59:15.530Z
2021-05-03 15:59:24.534Z
2021-05-03 15:59:33.537Z
2021-05-03 15:59:38.537Z
2021-05-03 15:59:40.536Z
2021-05-03 14:28:41.530Z
```

However, I wish to get the distinct values by the hour so the above should show something like this:

```
2021-05-03 15:00:00.000Z
2021-05-03 14:00:00.000Z
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Query

- group by

  - year of date (1-12)
  - day of year(1-366)
  - hour of day(0-23)
- keep only 1 date(all will have the same year/month/day/hour anyways)
- project to restore back the date using the fields we already have,
  the ones that we used to group

*all those operators have also optional `timezone: <tzExpression>`

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k2PrDhRE7tj)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "year": {
          "$year": "$date"
        },
        "day-of-year": {
          "$dayOfYear": "$date"
        },
        "hour": {
          "$hour": "$date"
        }
      },
      "date": {
        "$first": "$date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "date": {
        "$dateFromParts": {
          "year": "$_id.year",
          "day": "$_id.day-of-year",
          "hour": "$_id.hour"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Query2
(shorter version >= MongoDB v5, as suggested by the Wernfried Domschei in the comment)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W_0k4IpUpbE)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      truncatedOrderDate: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$date",
          unit: "hour",
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$truncatedOrderDate",
      
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: If you run MongoDB 5.0 or newer, you can use shorter `_id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$date", unit: "hour" } }`

Comment: @ Wernfried Domschei Would you mind sharing an answer how would you do it with dateTrunc. I have had some struggle with this. Thank you!

Comment: i added one `$dateTrunc` solution, but i think they both do the same, if you have an example that doesn't work, post the data if you can

Comment: the above groups same year+month+day+hour, if you want only by hour, ignoring the year/month/day its even simpler to do it, from your sample data i assumed you want year+month+day+hour also.